# SVG control not visible on top of Leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, svg, d3

I'm using Leaflet 0.7.1 and want to draw a radial menu (like openstreetmap's iD editor) on top using d3.
Some examples I found use Leaflet's overlayPane to append the svg element to:

```
var svgContainer= d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg");
```

On mouseclick, I add the menu and reposition it to the screen xy coords:

```
map.on('contextmenu', function(e) {
    console.log('contextmenu()');
    var tooltip;
    var center = [e.layerPoint.x, e.layerPoint.y];
    var menu = svgContainer.append('g')
        .attr("class", 'leaflet-zoom-hide')
        .attr('class', 'radial-menu')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + center + ')')
        .attr('opacity', 0);
        menu.transition()
            .attr('opacity', 1);

        menu.append('path')
            .attr('class', 'radial-menu-background')
            .attr('d', 'M' + r * Math.sin(a0) + ',' +
                             r * Math.cos(a0) +
                      ' A' + r + ',' + r + ' 0 ' + 0 + ',0 ' +
                             (r * Math.sin(a1) + 1e-3) + ',' +
                             (r * Math.cos(a1) + 1e-3)) // Force positive-length path (#1305)
            .attr('stroke-width', 50)
            .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round');
    });
```

Somehow, the SVG paths get drawn (this is visible in the Chrome Inspector) but are behind the map object.
When I 'drag' the SVG element just below the body tag in Inspector, I *can* see the circle paths.

Any ideas on how I can draw SVG 'menu' elements on top of Leaflet?

Thanks!!

[image: Screenshot]

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnijholt/7WNLt/1) for a demo. Right click or hold to add an invisible element.

Ps. I also asked this question [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685203/svg-control-not-visible-on-top-of-leaflet-js). Sorry for crossposting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. A colleague pointed out that the SVG container had no dimensions. Giving it the appropriate width and height proved to be the answer:

```
    svgContainer.attr("width", width).attr("height", height)
```